# MediaPlayer not working at all

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playback

I am a very beginner in Android, I am trying to make a MediaPlayer works but I have some errors.

1-If I click on play again , start playing twice at the same time.

2-If click on puse, doesn't happen anything.

3-My intention is to do a reproduction list with play, pause and stop.

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.android.allmusic;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class RomanticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean firstSongBoolean;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_romantic);


        TextView firstSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_song);
        firstSong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.primero);
                if (!mp.isPlaying()) {mp.start();}
            }
        });

        ImageView firstSongPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first_song_pause);
        firstSongPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.primero);
                if (mp.isPlaying()) { mp.pause(); }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring your [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) as a member variable, it should be enough to set it on your `onCreate`, but just declare it as an attribute of your class to test.

Since you are creating a new reference to the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) every time you click on the `ImageView` or the `TextView`, you don't the old reference to pause it or to know if it has already been started.

---

Code:

```
public class RomanticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean firstSongBoolean;

    //MediaPlayer as a member variable
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_romantic);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.primero);

        TextView firstSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_song);
        firstSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        ImageView firstSongPause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.first_song_pause);
        firstSongPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```